# Какие использовать регулярные выражения grep, чтобы скрыть расширения файлов?

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно вывести на экран типы файлов и их отсортировать. Эта команда работает, но никак не получается избавиться от имени файла. То есть выводится его имя+его тип. Поэскперементировал, но получается только сократить до расширения. Вопрос: что добавить в эту команду, чтобы не выводилось расширение файлов?

```
find -exec file {} \;| egrep -o '\.[^.\//]+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n  -k 1 -r | head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно использовать опцию `-b` программы *file*:

> -b, --brief
>   Do not prepend filenames to output lines (brief mode).

т.е.: «не предварять вывод именами файлов».

---

и *grep* в вашем случае излишен. равно как и опция `-k 1` у последнего вызова *sort*. а вот опции `-type f` у вызова программы *find* явно не хвататает.

---

```
$ find -type f -exec file -b {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```